# Mercurial -- Ignore certain files based on the existence of other files

Tags: mercurial

I use mercurial to keep track of a repository which contains both PDF files (generated by others, which I need to keep track of), and latex files, written by me.

For instance, assume a directory structure like this:

```
root
-  Requirements.pdf
-  MyReport.tex
-  MyReport.pdf
```

In this case, MyReport.pdf changes every time MyReport.tex does, and can be wholly determined by the contents of the tex file, so it should not be under version control.

I am looking for a way to tell mercurial to ignore such files. Obviously I can add a rule to `.hgignore` like this (http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hgignore.5.html)

```
syntax: glob
*.pdf
```

But that will ignore the PDFs that I *do* need to keep version controlled.

There's also this link: https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/TipsAndTricks#Avoid_merging_autogenerated_.28binary.29_files_.28PDF.29 but that doesn't really solve my problem either, because while it handles building the PDFs, it does not handle telling `hg` which files are important.

Or I could just do this manually, but I would like a way to script it, to make it more general, since these repositories can have several dozen tex and pdf files and manually managing this has become cumbersome.

It seems like quite a simple rule: If there is a file by the name of "blah.pdf", check to see if there is also a file name "blah.tex" and if so, ignore it, otherwise, pay attention to it. But I can't find anything about that.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such feature in Mercurial, nor in Git, nor will there likely ever be such a feature because it's extremely niche.  However, you might consider simply putting your "generated" files into a separate output subdirectory, and then ignoring all such directories.  For example, if you have an input like `foo/bar.tex`, the output could be `foo/gen/bar.tex`, and you could ignore `gen/`.

Answer (score 1):

> Obviously I can add a rule to .hgignore like this
>   (http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hgignore.5.html) ... But that will
>   ignore the PDFs that I do need to keep version controlled.

.hgignore ignore all newly added or existing **not versioned** files, **matching pattern**, but bolded texts give you at least two usable solutions:

- Write regexp, which means "all pdf, except some filename(s)" (with manually added filenames, most probably)
- use wide pattern, but add needed files into repository explicitly (`hg add FILENAME`)

Comment: Yes, that's true. What I meant was that it would by default ignore all PDFs but I could just manually add the ones I care about. That's the approach I've so far been using. It looks like I'll probably have to write an extension to do what I'm trying to do.